# Replacement for Varien_data_collection

Tags: magento2, varien

What is the replacement for `Varien_Data_Collection` in magento 2? I know that `Varien_Object` has been replaced with `\Magento\Framework\DataObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> replacement for Varien_Data_Collection in magento 2?
> ```

You can find the data collection class in Magento 2 by `your root\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection.php`

The class Implements

```
\IteratorAggregate, \Countable, ArrayInterface, CollectionDataSourceInterface
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to create temporary object collection. Is this helpful? **@Krishna**

Answer (score 1):

The replacement of `Varien_Data_Collection` is :

```
protected $_collectionFactory;
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory

    ) {
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

public function methodName(){
$collection=$this->collectionFactory2->create();
//this line of code should written in `foreach() loop` 
foreach($ArrayData as $RowData){
$varienObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();                    $varienObject->setData($RowData->getData());
$collection->addItem($varienObject);
// end `foreach() loop code`
}
}
```

**Note: This code is Tested**

Answer (score 0):

You can have alternative like this:

```
protected $_collectionFactory;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

            $collection=$this->_collectionFactory->create();

            foreach($result as $row){
                $varienObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(); 
                $varienObject->setData((array)$row);
                $collection->addItem($varienObject);
            }
```